# view page does not refresh after array pushing in angular

Tags: angular

I want to show the dashboard content for each user login, which varies for a different user. Here I have an array for content data which I have pushed.
problem is that when another user logged into the dashboard, the content does not change and shows the previous content.

I have tried the NgZone and BehaviourSubject property  but still, it shows the same

component.ts

```
     feeds: any[] = [];

     ngOnInit() {

        setTimeout(() => {
              this.getdata();   
             },1000)
    }

    getdata(){
         this.feeds = []
         this.myservice.getAllnotification().then((response:any)=>{
          let notfication = response.data
          let x=0;
           notfication .forEach(element => {
                    if(element.status==='Submitted')  
                        {
                          x++;
                        }
         })
          x > 0 ? this.feeds.push({ msg: 'You have '+x+' pending action 
           in'}) : '';

         this.myservice.getAllMessages().then((response:any)=>{
          let mes= response.data
          let y=0;
           mes.forEach(element => {
                    if(element.status==='Submitted')  
                        {
                          y++;
                        }
         })
          y > 0 ? this.feeds.push({ msg: 'You have '+y+' pending action 
           in'}) : '';
      }
```

view.html

```
     <ul class="feeds">
        <li *ngFor="let feed of feeds">
            <div><i></i></div> 
             {{feed.msg}} 
        </li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: First replace `feeds: any[] = [];` with `feeds: any = [];` and if possible please also post your API response here. and Have you tried observable for that?

Answer (score 1):

It's because Angular's change detection won't detect those changes since 'push' will just modify the existing object(array).
You can try writing `this.feeds = [...this.feeds]`(ES6 spread operator) at the bottom which will do a shallow copy of the old array and assign newly created array to `this.feeds`.
Or you can try injecting [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) and calling either its `markForCheck` or `detectChanges` methods.

Comment: i have added the  both  `markForCheck`  and  ` anddetectChanges` but issue still there

Comment: `constructor(`private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef`){}{ }    this.cdRef.markForCheck(); `

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify @watofundefined answer, I advise you use the [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) class instead of copying your array (for performances reasons).
Also you will have to use `markForCheck` methode only if you use the dectection strategy `OnPush`, if you don't use the `detectChanges` metho